# Database design for e-commerce site

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I am more of a frontend guy, so if these questions come out stupid, I apologize in advance :)

I am designing a database schema for an e-commerce site. The product sold on this site can contain other products. Eq: Think of a car as a product. Car can also contain other products like seats, steering wheel, windshield, etc, each of which can be sold separately.

**Question #1**: What should `Product` table have to take this into account? Does it make sense for a `Product` table to have a field called `Products` that contain all the productIds associated with this product? (or normalized into its own table for optimization)

**Question #2**: This site will also have discounts every now and then that can be applied to a product (either on an individual product or a product that contains other products). There are also discounts that is applied to an entire order. What is the best approach to design the Discount table?

Comment: Have a look at [Bill of Materials](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/bom/index.htm)

Comment: We are talking about homeworks?

Comment: Abe, I have gone through most of my questions again and accepted the ones I think are answered.
@danihp, yes, this question is purely for my learning purpose. As I mentioned, I am mainly a frontend guy, but figure I should diversify a bit :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with branching out ;) Keep it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

Do not include a column with comma separated IDs.  You will end up hating life. It's hard to query, hard to update and does not allow you to enforce data integrity.  I would recommend using something like this:

```
Product
--------
ProductId
ProductName
ParentProductId  --nullable
```

This will give you a table with a recursive hierarchical structure.  If the Product does not have any parents just leave the `ParentProductId` column null.

Question 2:

I would use this structure for the discounts:

```
ProductDiscounts
-----------------
DiscountId
ProductId  --nullable
Discount

Order
------
OrderId
DiscountId --nullable
OtherStuff
```

With this structure you would have to build in the logic to apply discounts without a specific product ID to the entire order.

Comment: Thanks, Abe. How would you differentiate discount for product vs discount for entire order? If ProductId = null, then it's order discount, like @evan suggested?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'll update my answer.  I would include a reference to the `Discount` table from the `Order` table also

Comment: Thanks, Abe. And I like the `ParentProductId` idea too. I will be accepting your answer if there is no better one.

Comment: Having one table for products and contained products will only allow a product to be contained in 1 parent product.  A seat could be in multiple types of car each of which would also contain steering wheels, a pen might come bundled with a notebook or a pen case, etc.

Comment: @evan, that is true.  I had assumed that products could only have one parent, but if that is not the case then your structure makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, this should fit your needs:

Q1.

Products table with ids
Contains table with multiple rows of containing product id and contained product id

Q2.

Discounts table which has:
Discount Start datetime
Discount End datetime
Amount decimal
Amount type - percentage or straight dollar amount
Product Id - if null then the discount applies to entire order, not just one product

Hope this helps.